sum of product of binomial coefficients
If we have the sum of two binomial coefficients,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{r}\binom m  k\binom{ n-m}{ r-k} = \binom n  r$$
We can use vandermonde's identity to prove this. The result is the familiar hypergeometric distribution.
Now, what I was wondering is if this formula:
$$\sum_{m=0}^{n}\binom m  k\binom{ n-m}{ r-k}$$
has some general solution.

The first has a simpler argument, based on just counting. I can't see a similar counting meaning in the second, but that doesn't mean it doesn't have,a closed form.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504335/proving-sum-k-0n-k-choose-a-n-k-choose-b-n1-choose-ab1?noredirect=1&lq=1
